# Python - Kivymd Error: Attribute Error: 'super' object has no attribute '__getattr__'

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I wrote this code for a Kivymd program for solving mathematical equations. I didn't add the solving objects because they are to long, However, I'll try to make the problem as clear as possible

This is the code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivy.properties import DictProperty
from kivymd.uix.screenmanager import MDScreenManager

__version__ = "1.0.0"

kv = """WindowManager:
    Home:
    Heugebra:

<Home>:
    name: "Home"


    FloatLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        MDCard:
            size: 500,400

            FloatLayout:
                size: 500,400

                MDTextField:
                    id: Equ
                    hint_text: "Insert the Equation"
                    size_hint: None,None
                    width: 200
                    pos_hint: {"x": 0.3,"y": 0.3}
                    on_text_validate: root.get_data()
                MDLabel:
                    id: Eq_anser
                    text: "test"
                    pos_hint: {"x": 0.4,"y": 0.3}
                MDRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "Cal"
                    pos_hint: {"x": 0.8,"y": 0.3}
                    on_press: app.get_data()
                MDRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "Expand"
                    pos_hint: {"X": 0.4, "y": 0.3}
                    on_press: app.expand()
                MDRoundFlatButton:
                    text: "Draw"
                    pos_hint: {"x": 0.4,"y": 0.25}
                    on_release:
                        app.root.current = "Heugebra"
                        root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                MDFloatingActionButtonSpeedDial:
                    data: app.data
                    root_button_anim: True
<Heugebra>:
    name: "Heugebra"

    MDRoundFlatButton:
        text: "Back to Home"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.3, "Y": 0.5}
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "Home"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"

"""

class WindowManager(MDScreenManager):
    pass

class Home(MDScreen):
    pass

class Heugebra(MDScreen):
    pass

class MAIN(MDApp):
    data = DictProperty()

    def on_start(self):
        Window.set_title('Every Solver')

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Indigo"
        self.data = {
                "Integrate": ["math-integral",
                        "on_press", lambda x: self.calculas('int')],
                "Diff": ["math-diff.png",
                        "on_press", lambda x: self.calculas('diff')],
        }
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

    def calculas(self, calc: str):
        print(calc)

    def get_data(self):
        x = self.root.ids.Equ.text
        self.root.ids.Eq_anser.text = "None"

    def expand(self):
        x = self.root.ids.Equ.text
        self.root.ids.Eq_anser.text = "None"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MAIN().run()
```

The problem is when ever I try to click the buttons "Sol" or "Expand", This error shows up:
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '**getattr**'. Did you mean: '**setattr**'?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the widget referenced by `self.root` (the `ScreenManager`) does not have the *Equ* or *Eq_anser* ids.

Note that **the ids are accessible within the rule where they were defined**, the dictionary containing those ids is the `ids` dictionary of the `Home` instance, which is the rule under which they are defined:

```
<Home>:
    name: "Home"
    FloatLayout:
        MDCard:
            FloatLayout:
                MDTextField:
                    id: Equ
                MDLabel:
                    id: Eq_anser
```

Therefore, to access them you need a reference to the `Home` instance. For example, since `self.root` is a `ScreenManager`, you can get a reference to the *Home* screen using the `get_screen` method:

```
def get_data(self):
    x = self.root.get_screen("Home").ids.Equ.text
    self.root.get_screen("Home").ids.Eq_anser.text = "None"

def expand(self):
    x = self.root.get_screen("Home").ids.Equ.text
    self.root.get_screen("Home").ids.Eq_anser.text = "None"
```